Equalizer global audio Independent in multiple channels
I want to Equalizer the Output audio of Android but in different Channels (left and right)separated. i can Equalizer of the global audio, but i can Not separate the Channels. I read the socumentation and Show only dynamicprocessing, but Doesnt Work, Any Idea how can i do it?
